# What are the difference between OODB & oop

Tags: oop, object, object-oriented-database

What are the differences between o-o DB and o-o programming languages?
Does o-o DB have all features in o-o programming like:
- Association
- polymorphism
- encapsulation
- Multiple inheritance

I couldn't find a direct answer to it

Comment: An OODB is simply a data store designed to store representations of objects. OODBs should be designed to incorporate the OOP foundations of Abstraction, Inheritance, Encapsulation and Polymorphism.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_database

Answer (score 1):

Initially there were procedural languages and data was stored relationally using foreign keys in tables.

After OOP languages were introduced the developer community observed mismatch between the two entities wiz OOP languages and DB. Since OOP concepts were not supported by the relational model. It caused lot of problems few of which are:

- **Granularity** - Since clearly we can see there are always more classes than tables.
- **Identity** - DB have concept like primary key but it's not there in OOP language
- **Associations** - OOP supports has-a and is-a relationships but in relational DB we miss is-a relationship.

To provide a solution for this paradigm mismatch few vendors came up with OODB systems.

OODBS was more like an extension than an datastore. This provided seamless integration with OOPL. Unfortunately there didn't happen much work on standards for this type of DB and it lacked maturity to be popular among developers.

The solution which is popular today to part the mismatch between OOPL and relational DB is called ORM solutions like we have Hibernate for Java.